# Etymology of "well" in "treat people well"

Tags: etymology

I wrote *treat people well*. In trying to feel more deeply about this, I wondered where the word *well* came from in this context. Why was this word chosen to explain and convey so much?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/well#Etymology_1

Comment: The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=well&allowed_in_frame=0) of the word *well* is available online. Is there more you'd like to know? If so, please edit your question to ask about that. Committees don't pick words, so it wasn't chosen as such, it's just the sound that got used by consensus.